# Form scrolls when I click on a button

Tags: .net, winforms

I've added a button in a panel at the bottom of a form.

The form has a scrollbar (`AutoScroll: true, AutoScrollMargin: 0, 0, AutoScrollMinSize: 10, 0`).

The panel with the button is partly hidden (depending on resolution), but the button is visible.

When I click on the button, the form jumps down, and the button doesn't register a click.

How can I make the button fire the click event, even if the form scrolls down (or instead of it - how can I make the button fire instead of the form scrolling when the button is clicked on)?

Comment: That's the "auto" in AutoScroll doing its job.  It isn't the click that triggers the scroll, it is the button getting the focus.  Underlying method is ScrollControlIntoView.  If you don't like auto-scrolling then you'll have to turn it off and set AutoScrollMinSize large enough.  But certainly better to think a bit about creating usable UI.